# Do atomics in C++11 prevent compiler to re-read from shared variables?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, memory-model

I'm looking for the second time at Herb's great "atomic weapons" talk and I'm trying to wrap my mind around the concepts that undergo the whole memory model / sequential consistency story.
There's one thing that now bothers me at the conceptual level.
On of the takeaway from the talk is that by using atomics we can "hint" the compiler about interactions between threads that the compiler wouldn't be able to detect otherwise.

So I started worrying about the following scenario:

```
int local_copy_of_shared_var = shared_var;
if (local_copy_of_shared_var > some_threshold)
{
   DoSomething();
}
... Do some work

if (local_copy_of_shared_var > some_threshold)
{
   DoSomethingElse();
}
```

In this case, as also pointed out by Hans Bohem in 'How to miscompile programs with “benign” data races' (with variable names adjusted accordingly for the snippet above):

> If the compiler decides that it needs to spill the register containing local_copy_of_shared_var between the two tests, it may well decide to avoid storing the value (it’s just a copy of shared_var, after all), and to instead simply re-read the value of shared_var for the second comparison involving local_copy_of_shared_var.
>
> [...] the core problem arises from the compiler taking advantage of the assumption that variable values cannot asynchronously change without an explicit assignment. Such an assumption is entirely legitimate if data races are disallowed by the language specification as in our setting. No such asynchronous changes are possible in the absence of a data race

Now, since atomics (with the default seq_cst memory ordering) should guarantee that there are no data races and since they are the "hint" to the compiler that there's interaction on such variables between different threads, could one argue that using atomics in the preceeding snippet would prevent the compiler to insert such "re-read" from **shared_var** and instead consider **local_copy_of_shared_var** as a "one-shot" snapshot avoiding the inconsitency between the two tests?

I think I have something wrong in my reasoning, because driven by common sense I wouldn't think that by just using atomics here I'd be guaranteed that the compiler will take measures so that **local_copy_of_shared_var** doesn't get updated between the two tests.
On the other hand, as Herb says in his talk, the memory model now guarantees that no spurious memory operations should be added by compilers when using atomics, which (looking at this case as a spurious read) would suggest again that this example is now "safe".
I'm very confused and would like to hear from the community and possibly get corrected if there's some bug in my reasoning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compilers don't get to just make code transformations willy-nilly, they have to follow the [*as-if* rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if), which basically states that the generated program must behave *as if* it executes the code as written in the input program. What makes the optimization you refer to admissible - even in old school C++03 - is that the compiler must be able to prove that the value of `shared_var` does not change between the two references to `local_copy_of_shared_var`. Typically that means that all the intervening code is visible to the compiler and that it contains no assignments to `shared_var`.

This optimization is still legal in C++11 if `shared_var` is a non-atomic type, since any concurrent modification of `shared_var` in another thread would be a data race, and hence undefined behavior. Making `shared_var` a C++11 atomic is a notice to the compiler that it *can't* prove that `shared_var` doesn't change between the two references, since it might be changed by another thread, and that this particular optimization would not comply with the *as-if* rule.

TLDR: Compilers in general are forbidden to introduce spurious reads *to atomics* as they would introduce data races.

Comment: In *all* C++03 implementations `volatile` should prevent reading again. Note that in the original use case of `volatile` — reading/writing memory-mapped registers — re-reading the value could have much worse effects than for shared variables: There a read may change the hardware state, so not only would the read value bogus, the assumptions of the program about the controlled hardware could be bogus as well. According to the standard, accessing a volatile variable is observable behaviour and therefore optimizations may neither optimize it away, nor add additional accesses.

Comment: @celtschk Very true, I was really thinking about the effect on reordering non-volatile accesses with respect to volatiles when I wrote that. Some implementations won't reorder non-volatiles with volatiles, some will - MSVC notably provides acquire-release semantics for volatile. But yes, it is certainly true that compilers cannot introduce spurious reads of volatiles as well.

Comment: I've removed the reference to `volatile` altogether so as not to confuse readers about exactly what guarantees `volatile` provides: understanding atomics is problem enough without throwing volatile into the mix.

Comment: I think a C++03 conforming compiler can also do the optimization even if some intervening code is not visible, if `shared_var` has automatic storage duration and the address `&shared_var` is never taken and no reference is ever bound to `shared_var`.

Comment: Coming back to my own question after long time, I'm getting suspicious about the TLDR line in the accepted answer: "TLDR: Compilers in general are forbidden to introduce spurious reads to atomics as they would introduce data races.". Isn't it true that atomics _never_ contribute to data races (even when using the "relaxed" memory ordering, see 1.10.5 in the standard)??

Comment: Maybe what you meant is "Compilers in general are forbidden to introduce spurious reads to atomics as they can no longer assume they won't be observing some asynchronous change caused by another thread that is writing to such atomics at the same time"?

Comment: @abigagli You're reversing cause and effect. The standard requires that atomics never contribute to data races. One of the consequences of that requirement is that compilers cannot introduce spurious reads, because doing so could introduce a data race.

Comment: @Casey, thanks for replying after so long, but, sorry, I still can't get my head around it. If what you say is true, then by the same token a program where thread A non-spuriously reads and thread B non-spuriously writes (i.e. both read and write are actually present in the source code) to a shared atomic would contain a data race? IOW: atomics only force the compiler not to introduce spurious accesses, but by themselves don't guarantee DRF if I explicitly introduce a data conflict (i.e. concurrent access with at least one write)? I'm even more confused now...

Comment: @Casey A data race by definition 1) doesn't involve a synchronisation primitive 2) can exist in an abstract execution (trace of abstract memory accesses) of the C/C++ program (not in the generated asm code). There is no such thing as "introducing a data race" during compilation. Assembly code can (in practice it always does) have races on accesses of memory locations. Data races make the C/C++ behavior undefined (UB). There is no such thing as UB at the CPU level. An invalid compilation would never "introduce a data race".

Comment: @abigagli Atomics by essence don't create data races, which don't have defined behavior. If they did, they would be perfectly useless! Of course any useful use of an atomic object must introduce a race condition, just like mutexes or any locking primitive.

Comment: @aschepler "_a C++03 conforming compiler can also_ (...)" under that hypothesis, any C++ version compiler can

Comment: @curiousguy Probably I wrote that because it was a comment on the end of the first paragraph?

Comment: @aschepler I see. I was also pointing out that such code transformation is valid even across synchronisation primitives (locking, unlocking, uses of atomics).